# Using a non-SLDS css library with LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, css3

We are building a Lightning Web Component using some of the native lightning components. However, we'd like to style it differently. Is it possible to import and apply a non-slds css library to LWC?

If not, what are some of the best practices to apply custom sytling to LWC components?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is. You can do so by using an `import` with `@salesforce/resource_url` module. Take a look at [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_third_party_library). Basically it comes down to these few lines:

```
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import SOME_CSS_FROM_STATIC_RESOURCE from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/d3';

export default class ClassName extends LightningElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        loadStyle(this, SOME_CSS_FROM_STATIC_RESOURCE);
    }
}
```

If you have a `.zip` file instead of single CSS you can load it this way:

```
loadStyle(this, SOME_ZIP_FILE + '/folderName/cssFileName.css');
```

---

EDIT: See @Renji-xD comments' with more technical background and recommendations regarding CSS in LWC.

Comment: one should add the note though that salesforce does not recommend to do it (especially when they including javascript) - also off platform and later with real shadow dom enablement css frameworks will stop working when they are just added globally

Comment: @Renji-xD I am not a front-end master at any way. Could you ellaborate on that or pass some links to explanation what and how exactly will that impact?

Comment: here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/265967/54495 and here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/264412/lwc-css-color-fill-for-lightningicon-not-working/264413#comment400206_264413:
For general explanation of shadow dom you can read the documenation here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_dom . With the "real" shadow dom global styles will not be applied to components by specification. Most likely sfdc will implement something to automate it but i think its still important to know whats happening (even in background potentially)